# Opencv Writing video as output.avi from video file not from webcam

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to write a video from video file it's not working but when I am using webcam code it's working 
there are 2 files one is file.py and the other is web.py
here is my file.py

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('People - 6387.mp4')

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)


        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()

out.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and this is my webcam.py this is working properly and writing video

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)


        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
cap.release()

out.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
```

Comment: Can you upload your video `People - 6387.mp4`?

Comment: Maybe the video `People - 6378.mp4`'s shape is not (640,480)

Comment: Define "It's not working".

Comment: @Dan Mašek
not working means in the output file its not writing video and the  output.avi and the size is 5kb

Comment: its working the video size which i have given was not correct it was 1920*1080 but i have given 640,480 thank you @HaBom